# Using TypeScript global variable with SharePoint functions

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint

Using TypeScript and Angular, I have created a function named `getTasks()` that I want to fire when a modal is closed. This is the function:

```
getTasks() {
 this.http.get(`https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items`).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data['value'])
  this.tasks = data['value']
 })
}
```

I can successfully create my modal with the following:

```
newTask() {
  var options = {
    url: `https://example.com/divisions/dev/lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?itemParent=${this.itemID}`,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: Function['createDelegate'](null, this.newTaskClosed)
  }
  window.parent['SP'].UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

This is my callback function that successfully logs when the modal has been closed:

```
newTaskClosed(result, value) {
  console.log(result, value)
  this.getTasks(); // Thinks that 'this' is null
}
```

Running this gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTasks' of null

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is `Function['createDelegate'](null, this.newTaskClosed)` doing?

Comment: @ABOS It fires the newTaskClosed function when the modal has been closed.

Comment: how do you bind `this` to this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/5648619) as a starting point.
By using an arrow function for the `dialogReturnValueCallback` property, I was able to keep the correct context of `this`. I also had success with referencing `this.getTasks()` through a variable that binds `this`.

Changing the `options` object to:

```
let options = {
  url: `https://portal.oldnational.com/divisions/it/iDemand/lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?itemParent=${this.itemID}`,
  dialogReturnValueCallback: () => this.getTasks()
}
```

or by using

```
let boundFunction = (function() {
  this.getTasks();
}).bind(this);

let options = {
  url: `https://portal.oldnational.com/divisions/it/iDemand/lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?itemParent=${this.itemID}`,
  dialogReturnValueCallback: boundFunction
}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the error when I test in my environment.

[image]

Test demo:

```
private newTask= (): void =>{
    var options = {
      url: this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl+`/lists/ParentA/NewForm.aspx`,
      dialogReturnValueCallback: Function['createDelegate'](null, this.newTaskClosed)
    }    
    window.parent['SP'].UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
  }
  private newTaskClosed= (result, value): void => {
    console.log(result, value);    
    this.getTasks(); // Thinks that 'this' is null
  }
  private getTasks= (): void => {
    alert('getTasks function')
   }
```

In Render function, call the dialog.

```
return (     
      <div >  
        <Button text="NewTask" onClick={this.newTask} />
```